# list element starting with 'a' ls command?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, ls

I have a repectory "apache2/mods-available". I want to list elements in 'mods-available' but only files beginning with 'a' and have the file extension '.conf' and list one file per line.

I tried like this :

```
user$ ls *a && *.conf ./apache2/mods-available
```

It didn't work.. any idea?

Comment: `ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf`

Comment: I got this : "apache2/mods-available/actions.conf" how can i do for to take or show just "action.conf" ?? :)

Comment: To print them one per line add `-1`, like `ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf`

Comment: I got this : "apache2/mods-available/actions.conf" how can i do for to take or show just "action.conf" ?? :)

Comment: ls -1 apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'

Comment: In the last example I meant `ls -1 apache2/mods-available/a*.conf`

Comment: Many options: 1) `(cd apache2/mods-available/; ls -1 a*.conf)`, 2) `ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | cut -d/ -f3`, 3) `ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | sed 's@.*/@@'`, 4) `ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

`ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf`

Comment: flag
 
Many options: 1) (cd apache2/mods-available/; ls -1 a*.conf), 2) ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | cut -d/ -f3, 3) ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | sed 's@.*/@@', 4) ls apache2/mods-available/a*.conf | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'